# LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't upload CSV data into MySQL table with no error

Tags: php, mysql, csv

**Update:**

I attempted to execute the query generated by PHP script in phpMyAdmin's SQL tab and got:

```
#7890 - Can't find file 'C:wamp    mpphpB4C4.tmp'.
```

It cut path between C:wamp and tmp file name. Could it be I'm escaping file path incorrectly?: `$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];`

---

I'm writing this cool webapp using PHP and MySQL. One of its functions is to upload contents of a CSV file into a table in my database called suites.

**CSV** file looks like this:

```
1230,Cool Business,,1
3612,Not-so-cool Business Ltd.,John Smith,0
```

Column meanings from left to right in this CSV go as such: Suite number, Name of the business operating at this suite, Primary contact(optional), Did I already go there?(0 - no, 1 - yes; optional also).

The database table, named suites, has the following structure:

**suite_id**(primary), **location_id**(foreign referencing locations table), **suite**, **business**, **contact**, **visited**

As you may have already guessed by now I'm trying to insert only the last 4 columns of the suites table with the above CSV example.

I attempt to do that with the following **PHP** code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class registration
 * handles the user registration
 */
class SuiteCSV
{
    /**
     * @var object $db_connection The database connection
     */
    private $db_connection = null;
    /**
     * @var array $errors Collection of error messages
     */
    public $errors = array();
    /**
     * @var array $messages Collection of success / neutral messages
     */
    public $messages = array();

    /**
     * the function "__construct()" automatically starts whenever an object of this class is created,
     * you know, when you do "$registration = new Registration();"
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(isset($_POST["add_suite_csv"])){
            $this->addSuiteCSV();
        }
    }

    /**
     * handles the entire registration process. checks all error possibilities
     * and creates a new user in the database if everything is fine
     */ 
    private function addSuiteCSV()
    {
        if (empty($_POST['suite_location_csv'])) {
            $this->errors[] = "Must select location of suite";
        }else{

        // create a database connection
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

        if (!$this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8")) {
                $this->errors[] = $this->db_connection->error;
        }

        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
            $suite_location_csv = $this->db_connection->real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['suite_location_csv'], ENT_QUOTES));
            if ($_FILES['csv']['size'] > 0) {
                $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
                $query = <<<eof
LOAD DATA INFILE '$file'
INTO TABLE sales.suites
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(suite,business,contact,visited)
SET location_id = $suite_location_csv
eof;

                $query_add_suite_csv = $this->db_connection->query($query);

                if ($query_add_suite_csv) {
                    $this->messages[] = "CSV has been uploaded.";
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "Sorry, I couldn't upload this CSV. Try again.";
                }

                var_dump($query_add_suite_csv);


            }else{
                $this->errors[] = "Must select CSV file for upload";
            }
        }else{
            $this->errors[] = "Database connection error";
        }
    }
}
}
```

**$suite_location** in this case is a value that user will select from a drop down menu on the upload form, which in turn is populated with another PHP script when page is loaded. Values of $suite_location are location_id values in locations table which has a foreign key in suite table.

So, the user picks a location, selects a CSV file and uploads it to the suites table.

Nothing is happening though. There are no errors. I've *looked* at LOAD DATA INFILE documentation and tried to apply what I've understood from it, but still doesn't seem to work.

Form snippet:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="admin_add_location.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addsuitecsv">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Select Locations:</label>
        <div class="">
            <select size="6" name="suite_location_csv">
                    <?php $location->getLocations(); ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label">Choose your file:</label>
        <div class="">
            <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn_success" name="add_suite_csv" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" ></span>Import CSV</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Add View PHP:

```
<?php
    // include the configs / constants for the database connection
    require_once("config/db.php");

    // load the login class
    require_once("classes/Login.php");

    // create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
    // so this single line handles the entire login process. in consequence, you can simply ...
    $login = new Login();

    // only administrators can see
    if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true && $_SESSION['user_group'] == 0) {
        require_once("classes/Location.php");
        $location = new location();
        require_once("classes/Suite.php");
        $suite = new Suite();
        require_once("classes/SuiteCSV.php");
        $suitecsv = new SuiteCSV();
        include("includes/header.php");
        include("views/admin_add_location_view.php");
        include("views/admin_add_suite_view.php");
        include("views/admin_add_suite_csv_view.php");
        include("includes/footer.php");
    }else{
        echo "<h1>Access denied</h1>";
        include("views/go_back_view.php");
    }
?>
```

Comment: did you try to execute the LOAD DATA INFILE command directly on the database to see if there are any errors?

Comment: does the form use a POST method and includes a valid enctype? and the input's name attribute is correct? you may also have a variable scope issue also.

Comment: @Fred-ii-

Yes. I'll add the code for the form too, I guess.

Comment: you may have a scope issue with the function, try it without `public function addSuiteCSV()` if it works, then you will need to be DB connection to the function. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. and check for errors on db side for the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Oh I am trying. Been trying since I posted this question. There was a syntax error with my LOAD DATA INFILE. I fixed that and it works now, but only if I run it on DB side. Now I'm trying to figure out why I can't upload it from my form. I created a separate class with DB connection info and all. Added dozens of if statements and one of them, the `"Sorry, couldnt upload CSV"`, keeps getting triggered. I var_dump'ed the query result variable but got false. So, I'm still looking into it at the moment.

Comment: The *"Sorry, couldnt upload CSV"*  is that where you presently have in your question as *"Something went wrong(I think)"*? If it isn't, then I would force a try/catch error, instead of just outputting an text echo like that. You need to find out exactly why it's failing.

Comment: @Fred-ii-
Not exactly. I've revised the PHP code in the question to reflect the entire class dedicated for this particular function called `SuiteCSV`. I'll try the `try/catch`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but I don't see an named element for `$_POST['suite_location_csv']` where you have `strip_tags($_POST['suite_location_csv']` plus, `strip_tags` isn't needed since you're escaping the data. That `strip_tags()` function may be causing more harm than good. One that is close to that is for `<select size="6" name="suite_location" required>` could it be related to that?

Comment: @Fred-ii-
That's been all ironed out. I've updated the form's snippet above. So, no it's not that. `Try/catch` isn't yielding anything either. I've added the main add view PHP code above. It renders all other views along wit this one on this one page and this is where also class instantiation happens, just in case.

Comment: I can't see the problem, after staring at this for the longest time. The only other thing that's unclear, is whether or not the session has been started, seeing you're using sessions `$_SESSION['user_group']` and if it's indeed set or not.

Comment: Try an echo and/or `var_dump($file);` after `$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];` if it shows something, then you know it's at least getting there. Try and put some of those throughout your code to see exactly "where" it's stopping/failing. That's about the best I can tell you at this stage. Use `var_dump();` on other variables too. There's nothing more I can do to help. I sincerely hope you find the solution and the cause, *cheers*

Comment: there is another thing I spotted in your `<select>` - `<?php $location->getLocations(); ?>` you're not echoing that. Try `<?php echo $location->getLocations(); ?>`

Comment: @Fred-ii-
It echoes inside the `getLocations();`

Comment: Plus, I don't see any `<option>` with values in your `<select>` so that's unclear as to how that is being populated. I tried testing this, but was unable to. That was my last ditch effort. Check your column types and lengths. Sometimes, MySQL fails silently because of that.

Comment: @Fred-ii-
It's all in `getLocation()`. Appreciate your time to help me.

Comment: just to make sure: when a user selects a file for upload and sends it to the server, you definitely have that file and that the file has a size > 0?

Comment: @Olli

Seems like it. In PHP script I echoed and var_dumped $_FILES and size is > 0 and has tmp_name and everything. So it must be going through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing:

`$file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];`

to:

`$file = addslashes($_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']);`

fixed the issue and CSV now gets uploaded.

Basically I had to escape slashes in the file path.